# Expected argument of type "?App\Entity\User", "string" given at property path "user"

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to learn Symfony on my own and I have a lot of questions

I'm making a news portal. The administrator can download news from an Excel file. I am converting a file to an associative array. For example:

```
[ 'Title' => 'Some title',
  'Text'  => 'Some text',
  'User'  => 'example@example.com',
  'Image' => 'https://loremflickr.com/640/360'
]
```

I then create a form to validate the fields in the file. There are no problems with the fields "Title", "Text", "Image". For "User" I created a Custom Validation Constraint because the User specifies an email in the file and I want to check if a user with that email exists in the database.

*Validation file*

```
class NewsImportType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title', TextType::class, [
                'constraints' =>
                [
                    new NotBlank(),
                    new Length(['min' => 256])
                ],
            ])
            ->add('text', TextareaType::class, [
                'constraints' =>
                [
                    new NotBlank(),
                    new Length(['max' => 1000])
                ],
            ])
            ->add('user', TextType::class, [
                'constraints' =>
                [
                    new NotBlank(),
                    new Email(),
                    new UserExists(),
                ],
            ])
            ->add('image', TextType::class, [
                'constraints' =>
                [
                    new NotBlank(),
                    new Length(['max' => 256]),
                    new Url()
                ],
            ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'allow_extra_fields' => true,
            'data_class' => News::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

*Custom Validation Constraint for User*

```
class UserExistsValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    public function __construct(private UserRepository $repository)
    {
    }

    public function validate($email, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        if (!$constraint instanceof UserExists) {
            throw new UnexpectedTypeException($constraint, UserAccountExists::class);
        }

        if (null === $email || '' === $email) {
            return;
        }

        if (!is_string($email)) {
            throw new UnexpectedValueException($email, 'string');
        }

        if (!$this->userExists($email)) {
            $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)->addViolation();
        }
    }

    private function userExists(string $email): bool
    {
        $user = $this->repository->findOneBy(array('email' => $email));

        return null !== $user;
    }
}
```

But the problem is that I am getting the error:

> Expected argument of type "?App\Entity\User", "string" given at
> property path "user".

As I understand it, the reason is that I bind the form to Entity News and the User field must be an object, not a string ('email').

*App\Entity\News.php*

```
class News implements EntityInterface
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    private $id;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 255)]
    private $title;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'text')]
    private $text;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 1000)]
    private $image;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: User::class, inversedBy: 'news')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: true)]
    private $user;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getTitle(): ?string
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function setTitle(string $title): self
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getText(): ?string
    {
        return $this->text;
    }

    public function setText(string $text): self
    {
        $this->text = $text;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getImage(): ?string
    {
        return $this->image;
    }

    public function setImage(string $image): self
    {
        $this->image = $image;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUser(): ?User
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    public function setUser(?User $user): self
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Please tell me how can I fix this problem.

**UPDATE**

Trying to create a DataTransformer

*EmailToUserTransformer.php*

```
class EmailToUserTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    public function __construct(private UserRepository $repository)
    {
    }
    //Трансформируем email в User
    public function transform($email): ?User
    {
        if (!$email) {
            return null;
        }

        $user = $this->repository->findOneBy(array('email' => $email));

        if (null === $user) {
            throw new TransformationFailedException(sprintf(
                'A user with email "%s" does not exist!',
                $email
            ));
        }

        return $user;
    }

    //Трансформируем User в email 
    public function reverseTransform($user): string
    {
        if (!$user) {
            return '';
        }

        return $user->getEmail();
    }
}
```

I get the error

> "Too few arguments to function App\Form\NewsImportType::__construct(),
> 0 passed in .. and exactly 1 expected"

Could this have something to do with how I'm building the form?

```
protected function buildForm(string $formType, array $formOptions = []): FormInterface
    {
        $validator = $this->validator;
        $formFactory = Forms::createFormFactoryBuilder()
            ->addExtension(new ValidatorExtension($validator))
            ->getFormFactory();

        $baseOptions = [
            'allow_extra_fields' => true
        ];

        return $formFactory
            ->create(
                $formType,
                null,
                array_merge($formOptions, $baseOptions)

            );
    }
```

Comment: From your [last question with my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71997494/symfony-constraint-for-user), you need to inject the `EntityManagerInterface` via the construct.  Then you can do `$user = $this->entityManager->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(array('email' => $email));` This just returns *true* or *false* (bool). Not sure why you have missed that out..

Comment: As far as I understand, to obtain information from the repository, you can refer to both the EntityManager and directly to a specific Repository. I tried to replace the repository with EntityManager (as you suggested), but the error persisted.
It can be somehow related to how I build the form (code above)?

Comment: You don't need that Transformer. You should not get that error.. Go over my answer again. Copy and paste them. You should have 2 files `UserExists.php` (this is the constaraint with message) and `UserExistsValidator.php` (this is the validator). Also place them in `src/Validator` folder (this is the namespace used in my answer)..

Comment: Also i take it your `News::class` has a property of *user*. If this is the case then this is what the error is. Add this to your form user property `'mapped' => false`.

Comment: Everything worked out!
I don't know how to express my gratitude to you, @Bossman!
Thank you very much for your help and your time!

Comment: Nice one! You're welcome, Irina :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [DataTransformer](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html)

```php
// src/Form/DataTransformer/EmailToUserTransformer.php
namespace App\Form\DataTransformer;

use App\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\DataTransformerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\TransformationFailedException;

class EmailToUserTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{

    public function __construct(private EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
    }

    public function transform(string $email): ?User 
    {
      if (null === $email) {
        return null;
      }
  
      $user = $this->entityManager
          ->getRepository(User::class)
          ->findOneBy(['email' => $email);

      if (null === $user) {
        throw new TransformationFailedException(sprintf(
                'A user with email "%s" does not exist!',
                $email
        ));
      }
  
      return $user;

    }

    public function reverseTransform(User $user): string
    {
      if (!$user) {
        return '';
      }
    
      return $user->getEmail();
    }
}
```

Then add the transformer in your form builder:

```php
public function __construct(private EmailToUserTransformer $transformer)
{

}

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
{
  // Rest of form here

  $builder->get('user')
    ->addModelTransformer($this->transformer);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I just tried this method and got an error. "Too few arguments to function App\Form\NewsImportType::__construct(), 0 passed in .. and exactly 1 expected".

Comment: Did you add the EmailToUserTransformer into your form's constructor?

Comment: Yes, sure. I have updated the information in the question. `private $transformer;

    public function __construct(EmailToUserTransformer $transformer)
    {
        $this->transformer = $transformer;
    }
`

Answer (score 0):

**you can add in your entity**

```
    public function __toString()
{
    return (string)$this->id;
}
```

it solve the error, but you cannot use 'choice_value' in formType because it always save ID of list generated in 'query_builder' from different entity